# How do I texture an arrayed mesh?

Tags: modifiers, uv

As an exercise in Tabletop Simulator modding and learning Blender, I'm trying to recreate the game Kingdom Builder. This game uses different tiles to construct a board for each game session. An example is at this link: https://sodaklady.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/p1010414.jpg

Based on the shape of the board, I thought it would make sense to make it out of a number of hexagons. I created a cylinder mesh with 6 sides and triangle fan fill type, and then used the Array modifier several times, applying the appropriate offsets, to create the right tile shape. Everything looks good up to this point.

[image: Blank board tile model]

Next, I want to UV unwrap it so I can paint different textures for each of the different tiles. My goal is to have the UV map match the board shape to make it easier to create different image textures. I selected all the edges around the outline of the top of the tile, used "Mark Seam" and then did UV --> Unwrap but the map looks very distorted, as shown below.

[image: Distorted UV mapping]

The top and bottom sides aren't even separated, even though I thought I would have detatched them via the Mark Seam command. I've tried watching some tutorials on UV unwrapping, but haven't found one that seems to cover this kind of case. I have the suspicion it's something to do with the Array modifier as I've seen arrayed meshes behave oddly when playing with other functions (e.g., using a Boolean modifier set to Difference with an arrayed mesh as the reference point does not produce the results I'd expect).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me toward a good tutorial on the subject?

Full disclosure, I'm a total Blender newbie. I've done some BlenderGuru YouTube tutorials that walk you through a number of the basic concepts while modeling a doughnut and coffee cup, but that's about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It may be a bit hard to say, you need to explain a little more about the way you made the mesh.

Mi guess is that you only create the shape with the array, but you didn't delete the faces in between, so, every hexagon is still a separate object but very close to the other so you don't notice that is a separate shape. If that is the case, you need to delete those faces to make a one mesh and then, unwrap all the final shape or UV Unwrap every hexagon individually

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Deleting the internal faces caused the distortion to go away. The UV map isn't quite the arrangement I wanted, but that's another question and at least there's no distortion.